# Android - Receive calendar reminder notification using NotificationListener service

Tags: java, android, notifications, calendar

I have two issues using NotificationListener service

1. I have using NotificationListenerService class in my app. This listener #onNotificationPosted method receive all notification.

My code like below

```
public class MyListener extends NotificationListenerService 
{
     public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification)
     {
       //Receive all notification.
       // I need to receive reminder notification only
     }
 //.....
 ......
}
//My Manifiest like below
 <service
        android:name=".MyListener"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

But I need to receive calendar reminder notification only.

How to add filter to receive calendar reminder notification only ?

2. When i turn on notification access , it shows below message

   **Allow notification access for MyApp?**

   *MyAPP will be able to read all notifications, including personal 
   information such as contact names and the text of messages that you 
   receive. It will also be able to dismiss notifications or tigger action 
   buttons that they contain*

How to change the above message in notification access dialog ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to add filter to receive calendar reminder notification only ?

- To filter for Google's Calendar we can listen for notifications
  posted with the `com.google.android.calendar` package name by using
  [`StatusBarNotification.getPackageName`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/StatusBarNotification.html#getPackageName()).
- To filter for reminder notifications we can listen for notifications
  posted with the `reminder` category using
  [`Notification.CATEGORY_REMINDER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#CATEGORY_REMINDER). (API 23+)

```
public class ReminderListenerService extends NotificationListenerService {

    private static final String CALENDAR_PKG = "com.google.android.calendar";

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        final Notification noti = sbn.getNotification();
        // Filter for the Calendar application
        final boolean isCalendar = CALENDAR_PKG.equals(sbn.getPackageName());
        // Filter for Notification.CATEGORY_REMINDER (API 23+)
        final boolean isReminder = Notification.CATEGORY_REMINDER.equals(noti.category);
        // Retrieve the reminder
        final String reminder = noti.extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
    }

}
```

**Lollipop**

I'm not sure how to filter for reminders in Lollipop, as far as the Google Calendar app goes. [`Notification.CATEGORY_EVENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#CATEGORY_EVENT) is used instead of something like [`NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#CATEGORY_REMINDER).

> How to change the above message in notification access dialog ?

You can't. But you could show your own dialog explaining why you need access and then direct the user to the notification listener settings using:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS)
```

Comment: Thanks @adneal, Reminder filter - As per your coding, It will check after notification posted. Is it possible do this before receive notification ?

Comment: No, that doesn't sound possible.

Comment: Thank you very much  @adneal

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver
        android:name=".Calendar.CatchChangesReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:priority="1000">
        <intent-filter>
            <!--   <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />-->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EVENT_REMINDER" />

            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:host="com.android.calendar" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

public class CatchChangesReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(CalendarContract.ACTION_EVENT_REMINDER)) {
        //Do Something Here to get EVENT ID
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        String alertTime = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        String selection = CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.ALARM_TIME + "=?";
        Cursor curs = context.getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.CONTENT_URI_BY_INSTANCE, new String[]{CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.EVENT_ID, CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.TITLE}, selection, new String[]{alertTime}, null);


    }

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Happy Singh, Is it possible to get notification title from onReceive method?